# MacOS C# Xamarin App with Objective-C Network Extension

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, macos, networkextension

I'm writing an app for MacOS and iOS that uses a NetworkExtension to provide some VPN capabilities.  It's written as a Xamarin.Forms app in C#, with the NetworkExtension also written in C#.  This is working as expected for MacOS, but in iOS we hit the 15MB memory limit and the extension is terminated.  Having stripped all possible extra C# dependencies out of the extension in an effort to keep its memory footprint small we still end up hitting that limit.

My assumption is that including the C# runtime itself is taking a good chunk of that memory.  To avoid that and have the extension be as trimmed as possible I plan to re-implement it in Objective-C.  The question then is how to bundle a C# app with an Objective-C NetworkExtension?  As far as I can tell, VisualStudio doesn't let me simply add an Objective-C project to a C# solution.  Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: This is not something I did myself, but it seems possible to do: 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/83693/ios-native-app-extensions-in-xamarin-ios-project

Comment: That looks like they encountered my exact same problem, thanks for Googling better than I did!  Once I've been able to test it out and make sure its still working I'll update back here again in case future searches find this question.

Comment: Happy to be helpful :)